# How to develop a Visualforce page with controls that could be switched between edit and view modes?

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object, iframe, create-records

I am new to salesforce and moved from .Net. I am given a simple exercise in VF page development.[image: VF page sample]. The page will look like the image attached. It will have 2 frames, the right one will have controls that could be used to enter new values/edit existing values/ view the existing values.

Left frame is going to have an option('New' button) to create a new record and a list of records available in a custom object with options to View/Edit/Delete.

I am not sure how to switch the controls between edit/create/view modes? . In asp.net has itemtemplate and edititemplate to do this job. Please suggest me a better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to have the right panel as an `<apex:outputPanel>` that would be reRendered based on the actions on the left.

For example, if you clicked "View" on "Record 1", it should call a method that returns the values of "Record 1". You can then use `reRender="idOfTheElementToReRender"` on an `<apex:commandButton>` or `<apex:commandLink>` to refresh the right panel and thus display the values returned by the method.

As for "New", you could have a form that is only displayed if a variable is equal to true. Something like below:

```
public Boolean isNew {
    get {
        if (isNew == null) {
            isNew = false;
        }

        return isNew;
    }
    set;
}

public void NewToggle() {
    if (isNew) {
        isNew = false;
    }
    else {
        isNew = true;
    }
}
```

Then you can display the form, using the `rendered` parameter. `rendered="{!isNew}"`.

Comment: +1, though you could have just written `isNew = !isNew` as a shortcut.